# Unable to hide and show fields with select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show and hide fields with respective selected value from  tag. But it is not working. This same code is working perfectly in my other site. But it is not working here, don't know which thing i am missing. Here is the code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
  <label>Product Type <sup>*</sup></label>
  <div class="select-wrp">
    <script>
      $('select')
        .change(function () {
          if ($(this).val() === 'single') {
            $('.single').show();
            $('.multiple').hide();
          } else {
            $('.multiple').show();
            $('.single').hide();
          }
        })
        .change();
    </script>

    <select name="product_type">
      <option value="single">Single</option>
      <option value="multiple">Multiple</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
  <input class="single" name="single" type="text" placeholder="100" />
  <input class="multiple" name="multiple" type="text" placeholder="100" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script needs to be told to wait for the window to be loaded first. You can use jQuery to do this by simply adding `$(() => { ... })` around your existing script:

```
  $(() => {
    $('select').change(function () {
      if ($(this).val() === "single") {
        $('.single').show();
        $('.multiple').hide();
      } else {
        $('.multiple').show();
        $('.single').hide();
      }
    }).change();
  });
```

Natively, you would use `window.onload = () => { ... };` instead.

Comment: It worked. Thank you Dean. Only 1 thing, it is loading Multiple input field when the page loads. But in <select>, Single is the first value that is selected by default, hence Single input field should be shown. Can you please guide that too. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure - I loaded the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pa8fv6gt/) and it only shows one field.

Comment: actually its placeholders are same. thats why it is looking to you as 1 field. Try one field placeholder as sinlge and second filed placeholder as multiple. you will see.

Comment: I have explained here what i am saying

https://www.loom.com/share/38f0dae34c0e4576b772c4dc4d76199d

Comment: I see only single on load, and multiple when I swap: https://jsfiddle.net/pa8fv6gt/1/

Comment: yes on JS fiddle i see same as you are. But try to see my link, in that Multiple field shows first. Have you seen that?

Comment: This can also been cleaned up using `toggle()` : https://jsfiddle.net/rok2txjz/